# Missing sentinel in UIAlertView allocation

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
    initWithTitle:@"Error"
    message:@"Some failure message"
    delegate:self 
    cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel"
    otherButtonTitles:@"retry", nil
];  
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

I got two warnings pointing at this block of code.

- Unused variable 'alert'
- Missing sentinel in function call

My code looks similar to all the examples online. Why is it broken?

Comment: missing sentinel is usually about forgotten `, nil`.

Comment: Thanks @Dani! Can't believe I forgot to do that :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code works fine for me. Try cleaning all targets and building again to see if the error persists.

Because you call `[alert show]`, you should not get an unused variable warning on `alert`.

Since you include `nil` after `otherButtonTitles`, you should not get a missing sentinel warning.

Comment: Cleaning the project worked. Man, XCode is really stupid. After searching around StackOverflow, I've found that many of the issues are resolved by either restarting XCode or cleaning.